# How to call a function inside router configuration?

Tags: angular

Im using a function to help me on router config building. The function make the route more beautiful, organized and easy to do maintenance, but im having problems with that.

Looks like the routes are not inside the routes array, because im not have errors and the routes being building correctly, but when im testing and writing the URL of one model, im redirected to NotFound page.

My helper functions:

```
function getAngularRouteStringPattern(model: Function) {
    let splitedName: string[] = model.name.split(/(?=[A-Z])/);
    return splitedName.join('-').toLowerCase();
}

function getLazyPath(model: Function) {
    let modelPascalCase = model.name;
    let modelAngularPattern = getAngularRouteStringPattern(model);
    return `app/modules/sistema/${modelAngularPattern}/${modelAngularPattern}.module#${modelPascalCase}Module`;
}

function getRoute(model: Function): Route {
    return <Route>{
        path: getAngularRouteStringPattern(model),
        loadChildren: getLazyPath(model)
    }
}

function getRoutes(models: Function[], staticRoutes?: Route[]): Route[] {
    let routes: Route[] = staticRoutes ? staticRoutes : [];

    models.forEach(model => {
        routes.push(getRoute(model));
    });

    return routes;
}
```

Models array:

```
const models = [
            User,
            Employer,
            Order
            ...
        ];
```

Routes array:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', component: AppComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
                children: getRoutes(models, [
                    {
                        path: '', redirectTo: 'about', pathMatch: 'full'
                    },
                    {
                        path: 'about',
                        component: AboutComponent
                    },
                    {
                        path: 'logoff',
                        component: LogoffComponent
                    }
                ])
            },
            {
                path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Comment: Provide your implementation of `getAngularRouteStringPattern` and `getLazyPath`.  Something is wrong in one of those 2 functions.

Comment: I have been add the implementation, but i know that all are working good with this functions. If i insert each object on router list, like `{
        path: getAngularRouteStringPattern(model),
        loadChildren: getLazyPath(model)
    }` all work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

After some time searching what is happening with my route i found the problem.

As is described on the angular page, about [router](https://angular.io/guide/router#configuration) configuration, the order of the routes in the configuration matters and this is by design, so when i join the static routes in front of the model routes, the '**' keyword with NotFoundPage is called, because it preceding the model routes.

Now, this is my router code:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', component: AppComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
                children: [
                    {
                        path: '', redirectTo: 'about', pathMatch: 'full'
                    },
                    {
                        path: 'about',
                        component: AboutComponent
                    },
                    ...getRoutes(models),
                    {
                        path: 'logoff',
                        component: LogoffComponent
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent
            }
        ]
    }
];
```